# How to resolve error Font-awesome library could not be found?

Tags: 8, theming

For some reason my Drupal 8 installation is issuing this error after I installed and enabled Fontawesome (via the commerce module).

I don't know

[image]

I think this is the dir it is asking me to check, but all seems fine

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to download [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/) and move files into the /libraries directory. It is explain in the documentation of the module [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/fontawesome)

And you had a clear warning message explaining that. You could have read the README.txt

Comment: I could not resolve the issue the way you mentioned it. I could not find a libraries folder unless in `drupal\modules\contrib\libraries` which is the only folder named libraries and it has nothing about fontawesome in it

Comment: Create a /libraries folder on the root folder of your project near modules, themes, core, and put the fontawesome directory on it.